# What is the psychological term for disregarding correct but unwanted information?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, terminology, bias

Sometimes people seem to be very resistant to information that is in conflict with prior beliefs, even when this new information is very plausible.

For example, a patient might change a doctor, because he/she does not get the diagnosis he/she expected even if the diagnosis is correct.

How is the psychological term for this tendency?

Comment: That would be "messenger-shooter," or a person who "shoots the messenger." King's messenger used to be a dangerous job, if you had to bring news the king wouldn't like.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Belief perseverance** is "the tendency to cling to one's initial belief even after receiving  new  information that  contradicts or dis-confirms  the basis of that belief" (Anderson, 2007).

Belief perseverance is usually regarded as a special case of the [confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias). (Also see [these](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8053/is-there-a-name-for-a-scientists-resistance-to-disconfirmation-of-his-or-her-th) [earlier](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/5825/how-to-refer-to-the-phenomenon-of-people-only-absorbing-evidence-which-confirms/5826#5826) [questions](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8614/what-is-the-name-of-a-cognitive-bias-by-which-existing-facts-are-tailored-to-fit/8616#8616).)

**References**

Anderson, C.A. (2007). Belief perseverance (pp. 109-110). In R. F. Baumeister & K. D. Vohs (Eds.), Encyclopedia of Social Psychology. Thousand Oaks, CA: Sage.

Comment: Believe perseverance is often regarded as a special case of [confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias). (Also see [these](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8053/is-there-a-name-for-a-scientists-resistance-to-disconfirmation-of-his-or-her-th) [earlier](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/5825/how-to-refer-to-the-phenomenon-of-people-only-absorbing-evidence-which-confirms/5826#5826)
 [questions](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8614/what-is-the-name-of-a-cognitive-bias-by-which-existing-facts-are-tailored-to-fit/8616#8616) )

Answer (score 6):

The term I would use is ["cognitive dissonance."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance) That is, there is "dissonance" between the result of one's cognitive processes, and the actual truth. According to psychologist Leon Festinger, people strive for internal consistency even at the expense of truth.

Comment: Isn't cognitive dissonance more like a conflict between two beliefs instead of a conflict between reality and belief?

Comment: @RobinKramer: In many cases, one of those to "beliefs" is what is true, and the other belief is what is believed, and the two are in conflict.

Comment: @RobinKramer the very Q states *conflict with prior beliefs*

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this just an effect of the [Confirmation Bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias)?